# How to use property file as a object repository in Selenium WebDriver Automation?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

How to use property files as a object repository in Selenium WebDriver Automation ?

I am seeking for instructions regarding the setup and the steps that need to be done to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

Create a **framework.properties** file and store the variables in this way(below are two locators with sample values)

```
locator1=username
locator2=password
```

Create a class for loading the properties file. You can use the snippet below:
Note:Path /src/main/resources/com/framework/properties/ is a sample path and may change as per your framework

```
public class PropertyManager {

private static final Properties PROPERTY = new Properties();
private static final String FRAMEWORKPROPERTIESPATH = "/src/main/resources/com/framework/properties/";
private static final Logger LOGGER = Logg.createLogger();

public static Properties loadPropertyFile(String propertyToLoad) {
    try {
        PROPERTY.load(new FileInputStream(System.getProperty("user.dir")
                + FRAMEWORKPROPERTIESPATH + propertyToLoad));
    } catch (IOException io) {
        LOGGER.info(
                "IOException in the loadFrameworkPropertyFile() method of the PropertyManager class",
                io);
        Runtime.getRuntime().halt(0);
    }
    return PROPERTY;
}
}
```

When you want to access the variables from the property class, use the snippet below:

```
private static final Properties LOCATORPROPERTIES = PropertyManager
        .loadPropertyFile("framework.properties");


public void click() {
    driver.findElement(By.id(LOCATORPROPERTIES.getProperty("locator1")));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create any file & save it with .properties extension 
For example - Add new file in eclipse By right click on project > New > File

> Add below data in config.properties file and save

```
Username = Jhon
Password = Qwerty123
```

Write Below code to access this file

```
String filepath = "./config.properties" ; // Path of .properties file
File f = new File(filepath); 
FileInputStream fs = new FileInputStream(f);

Properties pro = new Properties();
Pro.Load(fs);
pro.getProperty("Username"); // return value "Jhon"  return type string 
pro.getProperty("Password"); // retun  value "Qwerty123" return type string
```

Also use like  -

```
driver.findelement(By.id("user")).sendKeys(pro.getProperty("Username"));
driver.findelement(By.id("pass")).sendKeys(pro.getProperty("Password"));
```